# how to set individual user mail sending limit with whm/cpanel

Tags: linux, email, cpanel, whm, whmcs

can anyone knows that how to set individual user mail sending limits with WHM or C panel, i m facing spamming problem so i wish to set the limit per user and per hour.

For example :

There are two users. User1 and user 2

For user one, able to send 20 mails per hour
For user two, able to send 40 mails per hour.

I am using Dedicated server with whm cpanel.

Comment: Hello looks like you are having a general end-user issue rather than any coding/ integration problem. This question should be posted on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in WHM allows you to specify the maximum number of emails that each domain on your server can send per hour. This allows you to limit spam and better regulate bandwidth.

[check this cPanel documentation article](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Set+Email+Send+Limits)